# Problem with nested monads while writing a simple QuickCheck URL generator

Tags: haskell, uri, monads, quickcheck, do-notation

Another newbie question that probably results from me not having grasped Monadic `do` in Haskell: I want to write a simple QuickCheck generator for well-formed URIs, using the `Text.URI` type from the `modern-uri` package. To my understanding, there are two types of monads involved here: `MonadThrow` for error handling upon URI construction, and `Gen` from QuickCheck.

Here is my attempt to implement the generator. It does not type check:

```
import qualified Text.URI as URI

uriGen :: Gen URI.URI
uriGen = do
    sc <- elements ["https", "http", "ftps", "ftp"]
    tld <- elements [".com", ".org", ".edu"]
    hostName <- nonEmptySafeTextGen -- (:: Gen Text), a simple generator for printable text. 
    uri <- do
        scheme <- URI.mkScheme sc
        host <- URI.mkHost $ (hostName <> "." <> tld)
        return $ URI.URI (Just scheme) (Right (URI.Authority Nothing host Nothing)) Nothing [] Nothing
    return uri
```

My understanding is that the outer `do` block pertains to the `Gen` monad while the inner one handles `MonadThrow`. I attempt to unwrap the `Text` pieces from their `Gen` and then use the unwrapped `Text` to build up `URI` pieces, unwrap them from their `MonadThrow`, then reassemble the entire URI, and finally wrap it in a new `Gen`.

However, I get the following type-check error:

```
    • No instance for (MonadThrow Gen)
        arising from a use of ‘URI.mkScheme’
    • In a stmt of a 'do' block: scheme <- URI.mkScheme sc
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        uri <- do scheme <- URI.mkScheme sc
                  host <- URI.mkHost $ (hostName <> "." <> tld)
                  return
                    $ URI.URI
                        (Just scheme)
                        (Right (URI.Authority Nothing host Nothing))
                        Nothing
                        []
                        Nothing
```

From the error, I suspect that my intuition about unwrapping and wrapping the URI pieces is wrong. Where do I err? What would be the right intuition?

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Perhaps you could use `suchThatMap` and the `MonadThrow` instance for `Maybe`

Comment: An important detail: What do you want the program to do on failure? Should it retry until you get a valid URI or should it return a value indicating failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to nest the monads within each other, for example like this:

```hs
-- One instance for MonadThrow is Maybe, so this is a possible type signature
-- uriGen :: Gen (Maybe URI.URI)
uriGen :: MonadThrow m => Gen (m URI.URI)
uriGen = do
    sc <- elements ["https", "http", "ftps", "ftp"]
    tld <- elements [".com", ".org", ".edu"]
    hostName <- nonEmptySafeTextGen -- (:: Gen Text), a simple generator for printable text. 
    let uri = do
          scheme <- URI.mkScheme sc
          host <- URI.mkHost $ (hostName <> "." <> tld)
          return $ URI.URI
                   { uriScheme = Just scheme
                   , uriAuthority = Right (URI.Authority Nothing host Nothing)
                   , uriPath = Nothing  
                   , uriQuery = []
                   , uriFragment = Nothing
                   }

    return uri
```

Now the `uri` variable is interpreted as a pure value with respect to the `Gen` monad and the [`MonadThrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.0/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadThrow) will be wrapped as a separate layer inside it.

If you want it to retry until it succeeds, you can use [`suchThatMap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Gen.html#v:suchThatMap) as moonGoose suggested. For example like this:

```hs
uriGen' :: Gen URI.URI
uriGen' = suchThatMap uriGen id
```

---

This works because `suchThatMap` has type

```hs
suchThatMap :: Gen a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Gen b
```

so when you give it the identity function as a second argument, it becomes

```hs
\x -> suchThatMap x id :: Gen (Maybe b) -> Gen b
```

which matches the type above: `uriGen :: Gen (Maybe URI.URI)`.

---

**EDIT:** To answer your question in the comments:

`MonadThrow` is a typeclass that is a superclass of `Monad` (see [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.0/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadThrow)). What you wrote is equivalent to

```hs
uriGen :: Gen URI.URI
uriGen = do
    sc <- elements ["https", "http", "ftps", "ftp"]
    tld <- elements [".com", ".org", ".edu"]
    hostName <- nonEmptySafeTextGen
    scheme <- URI.mkScheme sc
    host <- URI.mkHost $ (hostName <> "." <> tld)
    URI.URI (Just scheme) (Right (URI.Authority Nothing host Nothing)) Nothing [] Nothing
```

In other words, the nesting of do has no effect and it tries to interpret everything in the `Gen` monad. Since `Gen` is not in the [list of instances for `MonadThrow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/exceptions-0.10.0/docs/Control-Monad-Catch.html#t:MonadThrow), you get the error complaining about that.

You can check which instances a type implements and which types implements  a type class using `:i` in `ghci`:

```
Prelude Test.QuickCheck> :i Gen
newtype Gen a
  = Test.QuickCheck.Gen.MkGen {Test.QuickCheck.Gen.unGen :: Test.QuickCheck.Random.QCGen
                                                            -> Int -> a}
    -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen’
instance [safe] Applicative Gen -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen’
instance [safe] Functor Gen -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen’
instance [safe] Monad Gen -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Gen’
instance [safe] Testable prop => Testable (Gen prop)
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Property’
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. For my understanding: Aside from the question what to do on failure, my type error resulted because I did use a monadic binding for `url` instead of a `let` binding? Because the outer monad is `Gen` instead of `MonadThrow`, that monadic binding doesn't type-check?

Comment: @UlrichSchuster I've updated my answer now. Does that clarify it? Yes, you're mostly right. The only detail is that `MonadThrow` is not just a single `Monad` but a class of monads, which include `Maybe`, `Either` and `IO`, but not `Gen`.

Comment: @UlrichSchuster If you look at how `do`-notation desugars, it might help you get an intuition for why it is equivalent: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation